# Should I normalize my model or go big-table for this kind of API (of virtual tables)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a web app that allows users to create "virtual tables" each with its own rows, columns and data. Each user will be able to CRUD their own virtual tables (using an API I am trying to build with django-rest-framework), but they should not be able to see other users' tables.

So far, my first attempt at a model looks like this:

```
class Vtable(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) 
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Vcolumn(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(Vtable)
    column_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Vrow(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(Vtable)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField('date added')

class Vdata(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(Vtable)
    row = models.ForeignKey(Vrow)
    column = models.ForeignKey(Vcolumn)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I just went through the tutorial for the django-rest-framework, and now I am not sure if it makes sense to normalize everything. Would it be better to have one big table instead? I imagine that it would be very very annoying to implement serialization as well as when permissions come into the mix. I am VERY new to Django, I am looking for some guidance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of thing you might want to consider storing each set of table data in a JSON field rather than trying to coerce database tables into a style they're not well suited too.

Using a plain JSON field for the table storage may or may not be suitable depending on what kind of lookups (if any) you'll need to perform inside tables, and how much data they'll contain, but it'd certainly be easier to work with.

You could still enforce constraints on the data in the table cells using REST framework's serializers or something similar to that, if you need to ensure that certain cells are of a particular data type.

Comment: That's a really cool idea, thanks! What if I still want to perform queries on each individual virtual table? Or if there's a chance that it can contain lots of data (maybe thousands of rows)? I am just worried that the JSON field may not be flexible enough for what I want.

Comment: Check the maximum size that your database of choice will allow for a given field - it should be pretty large, though you might need to tweak the config file or similar. If you do want to perform *some* types of queries then you could replicate (denormalize) some of the data as indexed columns. If none of that's going to work for your use case then you might find a document store better suited to your needs than a standard relational database (rethinkDB for example is excellent). Good luck!